# Difference between paired indexes and single column indexes?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm using this query:

```
SELECT SENSOR_ID, (BOX_COUNT * 6) AS BOX_COUNT, `TIME` AS `TIMESTAMP` 
FROM lu_sensor_log INNER JOIN lu_sensors S 
ON S.MACHINE_ID=1 AND S.ID=SENSOR_ID 
WHERE `TIME` >= '2013-09-04 15:30:00' AND `TIME` <= ' 2013-09-04 17:00:00' 
ORDER BY `TIME` ASC
```

It's a very simple query, nothing at all complicated. Previously, our database table had a paired index for `SENSOR_ID` and `TIME`. This query would take (on average) 4 seconds to complete. I've since removed the paired indexes and set individual indexes on the columns `SENSOR_ID` and `TIME` - Now the query is almost instant.

I've tried a quick google search about the differences, but can't seem to find any concrete evidence of why one method would be faster over the other.

Can anyone clear this up for me please? Why are single column indexes MUCH faster than a paired index on the same columns? (faster in this instance of course).

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wasn't using the paired index. You are restricting your data based on one of the columns at a time. Not both at once.

In fact you are just using the `TIME` index because of your `WHERE` clause. The paired index would have speed your query up if your `WHERE` clause restricts the `SENSOR_ID` additionally.

To see which indexes are really used you should have a look at the execution plan of the query.

Comment: That's brilliant thank you. As an aside, what is the difference between the two methods? I.e. Why would you choose one over the other? If it's not too broad a question. Cheers.

Comment: @LokiSinclair an index should reflect the criteria which you have in your `WHERE` clause. So it's pretty obvious in the most cases how to choose an index.